# Dataset directly from tf.train.SequenceExample

Tags: python, tensorflow, sequences, tensorflow-datasets

I'm working with a `NER`-like sequence tagging in `tensorflow` and decided to try `tf.data` to see if I can get IO performance improvements with my model.

At the moment I am employing `TFRecordWriter` to preprocess and save my training/validation data, which is a `tf.train.SequenceExample()` serialized to string. I then load it with `tf.data.TFRecordDataset`, parse/shuffle/padded_batch it and get on with training, which works fine.

**Question is**:

- is there a convenient way to make the `dataset` without first `serializing` and saving the SeuquenceExamples to `tfrecord` file?
- It seems to be an unnecessary step when I'll be running the predictions on new data. I've tried playing with `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()`, but it seems not suitable in this scenario as the inputs are sequences of different lengths that are not padded yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be possible to use [`tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) for this case. For example, let's say your examples look like the following very simple data, with two features (of which the second represents sequential data):

```
examples = [("foo", [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
            ("bar", [6, 7]),
            ("baz", [8, 9, 10])]
```

You could convert this to a `tf.data.Dataset` with the following code:

```
def example_generator():
  for string_feature, sequence_feature in examples:
    yield string_feature, sequence_feature

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    example_generator,
    output_types=(tf.string, tf.int32),
    output_shapes=([], [None]),  # A scalar and a variable-length vector.  
)
```

Comment: Yeah, I'll look into that a bit more. I thought about generators, but put them aside for now as I already have the parse function for SequenceExamples. Guess generators with a slightly different parse function is a way to go here.

Comment: Well, as a first step you could use a generator of `tf.string` elements that yields serialized `SequenceExample` protos, and then parse them with `dataset.map(lambda x: tf.parse_single_sequence_example(x, ...))`.  However I suspect the total amount of code will be much smaller if the generator yields one or more arrays of the appropriate type.

Comment: Well, as a first step you could use a generator of `tf.string` elements that yields serialized `SequenceExample` protos, and then parse them with `dataset.map(lambda x: tf.parse_single_sequence_example(x, ...))`.  However I suspect the total amount of code will be much smaller if the generator yields one or more arrays of the appropriate type.